# bottomNavigationBar are not displaying in the flutter

Tags: android, visual-studio, flutter

Hi I am trying to build an app in the flutter. I want to have bottom Navigation Bar in my screen. I am trying like below but it is not displaying bottom Navigation Bar .

When I have below code then it display the text correctly !!.
Does anyone know what is the reason of it ?
[image after Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOLXS.png)

```
    class _TabsScreenState extends State<TabsScreen> {

         void _selectScreen(int index) {
    setState(() {
     _selectedScreenIndex = index;
     });
}

 int _selectedScreenIndex = 0;

late List<Map<String, Object>> _screens;

 @override
  void initState() {
   _screens = [
      {
        'Screen': CentersScreen(),
        'Title': ' الصفحة الرئيسية',
       },
      {
        'Screen': AdvertisementScreen(),
         'Title': 'صفحة الإعلانات',
       },
      {
         'Screen': ProfileScreen(),
          'Title': ' الملف الشخصي ',
        },
      ];
       super.initState();
      }

     @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                 title: Text(_screens[_selectedScreenIndex]['Title'].toString()),
                 backgroundColor: Colors.purple[300],
                      ),
                 body: _screens[_selectedScreenIndex]['Screen']as Widget,
                      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
                      onTap: _selectScreen,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.purple[300],
                      selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                      unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
                      currentIndex: _selectedScreenIndex,
                       items: [
                        BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
                        label: 'الرئيسية',
                                ),
                       BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.campaign_rounded),
                         label: 'الاعلانات',
                            ),
                          BottomNavigationBarItem(
                           icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                            label: 'حسابي',
                              ),
                            ],
                        ),
                    );
                }
             }
```

Comment: I tried your code it's showing the Bottom Navigation bar without any problem
try to restart the app and check if it works or not 
I just copied your code.

Comment: ممكن يكون المشكله في الكود بداخل ال screens وليس كود ال bottom navigation bar

Comment: طيب عادي اوريك الاكواد وتشوف وين المشكله ؟

Comment: sure I will help if I could if you cannot put your code here You can send it Fady.fouad.a@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
  class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _indexNow = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> _screens = [
      screen1(),
      screen2(),
      screen3(),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Some text"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: _screens[_indexNow],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _indexNow,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        fixedColor: Colors.black,
        onTap: (indice) {
          setState(() {
            _indexNow = indice;
          });
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
            label: "Text screen1",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.book),
            label: "Text screen2",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.video_camera_back),
            label: "Text screen3",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope to help you!

Comment: I tried this code but the same problem :(